Prevent accidental touch while speaking on GrapheneOS (AOSP)
I've got a Google Pixel 8 Pro running GrapheneOS. When I'm on the phone talking to somebody and hold the phone to my ear, it very often accidentally registers taps. This e.g. leads to activation of the flashlight or Bluetooth by the slide-down menu. Locking the screen after answering the call does not help, probably because the slide-down menu is accessible anyway. I cannot find any setting to prevent this. Does anyone have the same issue or any idea of how to fix this?
I used the app Sensors Toolbox to check whether the proximity sensor works as it should. And it does. However, it only detects small distances at the top of the phone (where the ear should be during the call, which is not always the case). If the phone detects a small distance to the skin during the call, the screen is deactivated, but is activated if the phone slips a little from that position. Is this normal?

Most phones have a proximity sensor that detects if the phone is close to the body (distance about 5cm or less) and then disable the screen. Use an app like Sensors  to test availability and functionality of proximity sensor.

I've just installed this app and the proximity sensors seems to work. I've edited the question.

The proximity sensors I have encountered were always "digital" - 0 or 1 which means a proximity of 0 cm or 5 cm (tested on my Pixel devices).

I can confim that. Maybe it's just my way of holding the phone :(
